# How to set custom ProducerListener when using multiple (or any named) spring cloud stream binders in SpringBoot 2.3

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka

With SpringBoot 2.4 and above I can use [BinderCustomizer](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/current/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream.html#binder-customizer) to set a custom Kafka ProducerListener.

Is there a way to do the same with SpringBoot 2.3 and Spring Cloud version `Hoxton.SR12`?
`Hoxton.SR12` uses `spring-cloud-stream:3.0.13.RELEASE` which does not have `BinderCustomizer`.

Comment: No those versions have been out of support for a long time now; the only 2.x version of Boot that is supported is 2.7.x. https://spring.io/projects/spring-boot#support similarly, 3.2.x for stream: https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud-stream#support